# How to make image background embossed effect

Tags: html, css

I really don't know how to name my problem but I have a *psd* file that looks something like this:

[image]

Every item in the image above is a single image like this one:
[image]

I don't have a good specification about this, that's all I know about it. So I have been thinking maybe I can use the whole image as sprite background.

Please share your thoughts how to achieve something like this and if you are familiar please edit the question name precisely cause I could not.

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can I achieve this effect [which I don't know how to name it]

Comment: It's an embossed effect.  Not so easy to achieve without Photoshop.  Although you could fake it by using 3 different colored images and offsetting them by 2 pixels or so.

Comment: You'll likely want to create an image sprite from the inset embossed effect.

Comment: @hungerstar yes, I was thinking about it, but I thought there is some CSS filter that would the effect. Thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

Here is an great article which accomplishes this using `text-shadow`: [**7 Great CSS based text effects using the text-shadow property**](http://www.midwinter-dg.com/permalink-7-great-css-based-text-effects-using-the-text-shadow-property_2011-03-03.html)

Here is an example how it looks: [**Hello World example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/KVNVqQ)

Code:

```
h1 {
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #fff, 1px 1px 1px #000;
    color: #9c8468;
    opacity: 0.3;
    font: 80px 'Museo700';
}
```

I didn't include the right font, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but don't think it would help me cause in my case I have images, not a text. Thanks anyway, nice example

Comment: Well if you decide to use pure css solution in the future i think this will be come in handy and be more performant and scalabe.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's why I asked the question in first place, cause I don't want to go with sprites on this one

Answer (score 0):

This is what you do...  I just did this in Photoshop, and the results are pretty good.  It can be duplicated in CSS.

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1z9H.png" id="front"/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1z9H.png" id="middle"/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1z9H.png" id="back"/>
```

Each of those images should be a different color.  Front, as it is.  Middle, dark gray, and back, white.

Use CSS is place them in the same spot, but offset by a couple of pixels.

```
#front {
    top:5px;
    left:5px
}
#middle {
    top:3px;
    left:5px
}
#bottom {
    top:7px;
    left:5px
}
```

Comment: Why would you use multiple images instead of one?

Comment: Only because they are different colors.  It's just a matter of a visual effect for the sake of CSS.  If it were me, I'd do it with PhotoShop anyway and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

CSS now has filters. (not yet fully supported)
  [view example](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html)
  [view notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

You can use **drop-shadow**

- **box-shadow** even with transparent .svgs kept the retangular shadow.
- works like **text-shadow** but for vector images (.svg)

*side note:* Since it's not yet fully supported, use an image editing software.